# Исключить повторы в XML файле

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Моя задача - получить XML следующего вида:

```
 <Sets>
  <Set name="L: Line1 L1R701">
    <data>
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="322" MIN_1="-286" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="326" MIN_1="-290" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="339" MIN_1="-279" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="342" MIN_1="-286" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="346" MIN_1="-268" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="367" MIN_1="-275" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="368" MIN_1="-275" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="368" MIN_1="-271" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="377" MIN_1="-272" />
    </data>
  </Set>
</Sets>
```

Но в результате выполнения запроса я получаю следующее:

```
<Sets>
  <Set name="L: Line1 L1R701">
    <data>
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="322" MIN_1="-286" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="326" MIN_1="-290" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="339" MIN_1="-279" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="342" MIN_1="-286" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="346" MIN_1="-268" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="367" MIN_1="-275" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="368" MIN_1="-275" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="368" MIN_1="-271" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="377" MIN_1="-272" />
    </data>
  </Set>
  <Set name="L: Line1 L1R701">
    <data>
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="322" MIN_1="-286" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="326" MIN_1="-290" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="339" MIN_1="-279" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="342" MIN_1="-286" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="346" MIN_1="-268" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="367" MIN_1="-275" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="368" MIN_1="-275" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="368" MIN_1="-271" />
      <values Line_CD="1" ROBOT_NM="L1R701" MAX_1="377" MIN_1="-272" />
    </data>
  </Set>
</Sets>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы результат выводился только один?

Код моего запроса:

```
SELECT 
            CONCAT('L: ', LINE.LINE_NAME, ' ', DATA.ROBOT_NM) as '@name'
            ,
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    TRQ.LINE_CD as 'values/@Line_CD',
                    TRQ.ROBOT_NM as 'values/@ROBOT_NM',
                    CAST (TRQ.MAX_1 as int) as 'values/@MAX_1',
                    CAST (TRQ.MIN_1 as int) as 'values/@MIN_1'

                    FROM RB_TRQ_DT_TBL as TRQ
                    WHERE (TRQ.ROBOT_NM = DATA.ROBOT_NM AND TRQ.LINE_CD = DATA.LINE_CD AND TRQ.UP_DATE between @DateStart and @DateStop)
                    FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('data'), TYPE
            ) 
        FROM RB_TRQ_DT_TBL as DATA
        JOIN RB_LINE_TBL as LINE
        ON (DATA.ROBOT_NM = @Name AND LINE.LINE_CD = DATA.LINE_CD)
        FOR XML PATH('Set'), ROOT('Sets')
```

Comment: добавить `distinct`  в основной запрос? или дописать условия (в where/join), так чтобы он только одну строку возвращал? хотя не понятно, будет ли дистинкт работать  с xml столбцом

Answer (score 0):

Изменить основной запрос на SELECT TOP 1. Distinct с XML не работает